# React native - simple component using array map

Tags: react-native

I should create an array of clickable component using array.map,  but the debugger returns errors about the index after a click.

```
const iconsArray=['Q','W','E','R','T','Y','U','I','O','P','A','S','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','Z','X','C','V','B','N','M','a'];

const showIcons = iconsArray.map((index)=>{

    return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={(index)=>this.chooseIcon(index)} style={styles.containerIcon} key={index}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.iconStyle}>{index}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity> 
    );
  });
```

[the return from the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yqNN.png)

Comment: is it compulsory to use array.map? You can try with Flatlist!

Comment: Your code looks fine. How are you using showIcons? You should add that snippet as well

Comment: showIcons is a method that call a redux function that pass the character(that represents a simbol in a ttf file). the idea is that alfer a click on a icon that appears in other location in same page. My problem, after the Hisman's answer, is where I can use IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Each of your Touchable component should have a prop named key with unique value for each. This helps react to keep track of the components that are listed and the actions that you perform on them.

The key should be unique, so better to have your array items with its value and an ID for each item in array, and instead of direct string array, have an object array.